# Magento 2 How to Create a Custom Console Command

Tags: magento2, command-line

Is it possible to create a new Magento command for example to delete the generation folder?

Comment: Do you mean run a script?

Comment: No, I mean command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've created several useful commands, which are useful for us who develop Magento 2 sites on a daily basis. Magento 2 console commands are based on symphony, you can create commands for your personal/team use something like `bin/magento cache:clean`. This way you can execute the command directly from the terminal.

Here is a simple hello world command. Before we get started clear you generation folder and here is what you need to do.

Create a new module for illustration purposes I'll call it `Tools` under `app/code/Andre/`, include the `registration.php` and `module.xml`.

**app/code/Andre/Tools/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Andre_Tools',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Andre/Tools/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Andre_Tools" setup_version="0.1.0"/>
</config>
```

Create a new model class, this is where it will contains the options, description and the logic of your command.

**app/code/Andre/Tools/Model/Generation.php**

```
<?php
namespace Andre\Tools\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Generation extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('generation:clean')
             ->setDescription('The description of you command here!');

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

**app/code/Andre/Tools/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="clean" xsi:type="object">Andre\Tools\Model\Generation</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Lastly do a `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, check that the module is active `bin/magento module:status` if not then run `bin/magento module:enable Andre_Tools`.

Now to run the command you just create simply run:

```
 bin/magento generation:clean
```

Now just add your own logic under the `execute()` method, to delete the generation folder.

Comment: Besides all these, when in `production` mode, don't forget to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. Otherwise your new command won't show up / work (even after cleaning cache).

Comment: Awesome, thanks Andre!

Answer (score 0):

Here the Vendor is `Store` and module name is `Tools`

Create these files:

```
app/code/Store/Tools/etc/di.xml
app/code/Store/Tools/etc/module.xml
app/code/Store/Tools/registration.php
app/code/Store/Tools/Console/Command/Generation.php
```

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="delete_generation" xsi:type="object">Store\Tools\Console\Command\Generation</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
    </config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Store_Tools" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Store_Tools',
    __DIR__
);
```

Generation.php :

```
namespace Store\Tools\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command; // for parent class
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface; // for InputInterface used in execute method
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface; // for OutputInterface used in execute method
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class Generation extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('clear:generation')
             ->setDescription('Clear var/generation folder!');

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $fs = new Filesystem();
        try {
            if($fs->exists('var/generation')){
                $fs->remove(array('var/generation'));
                $output->writeln('Cleared generation!');
            }
            else {
             $output->writeln('Can\'t find directory');
            }
        } catch (IOExceptionInterface $e) {
            echo "An error occurred while deleting your directory at ".$e->getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade

And you are ready to use the command like this

```
php bin/magento clear:generation
```