# Command line enable / disable static blocks

Tags: cron, static-block, command-line

I would like to be able to enable and disable static blocks via the command line, is there a utility that provides this functionality.

My use case is to configure a cron job to periodically enable then disable a static block.

Comment: Create your own Custom Console Command . follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150547/magento-2-how-to-create-a-custom-console-command

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: no.

You will need to create the command line, or better yet, create a cron that enables/disables it.

I am guessing you are using open source magento, since the enterprise edition has a staging module that you can schedule changes.