# magento2 build image updater service which run through all created products and add missing images to product

Tags: magento2

I have some products created, but they do not have images when i see them in frontend or backend. I have these missing images in one folder with the format of productSku.png.
I want to build image updater service which run through all created products and add missing images to product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution - use the Magento Product Images import functionality:

1. Write a simple php script which collects all your SKUs from the filenames from your images folder and creates a CSV file with the product SKU on first column, then the base_image, small_image, thumbnail_image, or additional_images on the other columns filled with the image filename.
2. Move all your images in the <project_root>/var/import/images/ folder.
3. Use the Magento [product images importer](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-import-product-images.html#method-1-import-images-from-the-local-server) guideline to import the CSV file previously created.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before with an [external bootstrap script](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script). It would also be possible with a [custom module cli](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150547/magento-2-how-to-create-a-custom-console-command) command.

You need to give consideration to the type of product (simple, configurable, grouped etc), and the image roles you require i.e swatch images. If you have a multi store setup you also need to check if your image role attributes are set to store view or global - i.e. do you want the same images for all store views.

You will need to be able to correlate your images in your folder with your product stock-keeping unit (SKU). This is best achieved by consistently renaming the images. For example if the product sku is `ABC-01` and your image is `product-image-abc-01.jpg` then you will need to determine the image filename from the sku.

To find your missing images load a product collection (all products) and parse each products media gallery data

```
$_existingMediaGalleryEntries = $_product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
$_imageRoles=array();
foreach ($_existingMediaGalleryEntries as $entry) {
    $_imageRoles[]=$entry->getTypes();
}
```

if `$_imageRoles[]` is empty, the product (probably) has no image.

Set your store view

```
$_store = $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore($_storeId);
$this->_storeManagerInterface->setCurrentStore($_store);
```

then loop through the products with missing images, loading them using the product repository

```
$_product = $this->_productRepository->get($_sku);
```

Clear and then set the image data depending on the product type and the roles you require. The folder with your images in `$_imageImportPath` must be relative to the Magento `pub/media/import` folder.

```
$_product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
if ($_productType === 'simple')
{
    $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($_imageImportPath, array('swatch_image','image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
} else {
    $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($_imageImportPath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
}
```

When the image data is set you can save the product.

```
try {

    $this->_productRepository->save($_product);

    }

    catch(\Exceptionagento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {

      // catch NoSuchEntityException

    }
```